# Quiz game - how to save already asked questions? Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to create a quiz game with arround 5000 questions using android studio. Since i am not familiar with Sqlite database 
i will use a seperate java class as a question Bank. My problem is the following: How can i optimize the question selection
in order not to show already asked questions every time that a new game will start. Moreover, i don't want the questions order to be standard
(i want something like a shuffle to the question list but only for the first time that the app is launched). Is there a way to save the 
questions that have already been asked?

Comment: Use ``boolean asked;`` and set its value to ``true`` after the question has been asked.

Comment: Remove from queue

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the questions into a List like so:

```
List<String> Questions;
```

You can shuffle the questions using the following method.

```
Collections.shuffle(Questions);
```

And assuming you loop through the questions starting from index 0, you could remove them from the List using index 0, as everytime you remove the first element of the list, the List will ultimately "shift" left by 1.

```
Questions.remove(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove asked question You can use streams. Some example below:

> ```
> List<Question> questionList = new ArrayList();
> List<Question> result = questionList.stream()
>     .filter(question -> true==(question.asked))
>     .collect(Collectors.toList());
> result.forEach(System.out::println);
> ```

2. To shuffle I think Collections would be fine:

> Collections.shuffle(questionList);